# Show title of the category chosen in "Products by category" gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

I am displaying a gutenberg block "**Products by category**" on a page. I have selected a category with the name e.g. shirts and now I would like to display the name of the category also above this block. The block which now only shows the products from that category.

Is there such an option within this block or is there perhaps another way to display a category title with a woocommerce gutenberg block that I am missing?

I prefer not to use a shortcode block as demonstrated in this answer
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/339024

Thanks in advance